# Replace nan with empty string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

**My requirement:**
I want to replace `nan` with `""`(empty string)

**Example**

```
data = """{"name":"siva","id":"111","grade":"12","job_id":nan,"location":"ananb"}"""
```

If you see above example, i just want to replace `nan`(Not a Number) not the string consists of nan(ananb)

**Can any one suggest a solution for this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non generic solution for your specific example could be

```
data.replace(":nan",":")
```

This wouldn't replace actual values of the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string.replace method.

```
data.replace("nan","")
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: it will replace `ananb` as well, but  i just want to replace only `nan` not other strings conatins `nan` in it

Comment: Think that this will replace any appearance of "nan" in the entire string, and for example will also replace "ananb", can use regex replace and replace every nan sorrounded by `\b`s

Comment: i don't want to replace `ananb`. i just want to replace `nan`.

Comment: If you know that the nan is always going to be at that specific value in the string, you can use data.replace('nan', '', 1) -> Will only replace the first instance.

Otherwise, you have to use regex I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Better one would be to replace any match of `nan` which not sorrounded by other letters using regex ike so:

`import re`

`print(re.sub("\Wnan\W", "", data))`